# Misuse of the verb allege?

Tags: phrases, expressions, mass-media

I recently visited Jordan on a business trip. Read the following in a newspaper:

> Bleeding profusely, she pleaded with the **alleged** attacker, **Mushataq**, to
>   take her to a hospital.

*My understanding is that if we accuse someone of committing a crime but the proof of the wrongdoing isn't yet found, use the verb allege.*

- Is the phrasing correct or it's a misuse of the verb allege?

Comment: Dunno about Jordan, but in the US the general tendency in the press is to use "alleged" until the perp is convicted, even if there are Technicolor 3-D movies of him committing the crime, and even if he's written a confession.

Comment: Good question, and indeed, the name (and identity) may be alleged, but it is _unlikely_ that she pleaded with a man she thought might have been her attacker - it is likely she was pretty sure he was the attacker, even though his identity may not be legally established yet.

Comment: @oerkelens - Part of my point is that even if she knew him and had photos of him, in the US it's still "alleged" (or "accused") until he's convicted.

Comment: @HotLicks: no, that is not the point. She _did_ plead with the attacker. Whoever that was, and whether that was Mushataq or Santa, there is absolutely no allegation about who she pleaded with, that was her attacker. No court case will change that. Now, whether the attacker was mr Mushataq, or whether mr Mushataq was the attacker, _that_ is what you want to carefully word.

Comment: In journalism it's best to think of the word "alleged" as just a flag raised by the writer saying "not yet proven in court, so don't sue me".

Comment: @oerkelens - If she "pleaded with her attacker" or "pleaded with Mushataq" then no "alleged" is needed.  But put them together in a sentence (as was done above) and, per standard US press practices, you need the word.

Comment: @HotLicks: The sentence as it stands is an abomination. Standard press practice should be to make a distinction between the description of events and a description of the people involved - because in the current sentence, she supposedly pleaded with a guy that she suspected of having attacked her. There are plenty of ways to write a better sentence, but whoever wrote this one just missed out on them. It's poor language, whatever legal or political guidelines are followed.

Comment: @oerkelens - No, it's *allegedly* poor language.  The writer has not been convicted yet.

Comment: @HotLicks - So, to satisfy that, I guess the sentence could be rewritten as: "Bleeding profusely, she pleaded with her attacker, allegedly Mr Mushataq, to take her to a hospital."

Comment: weakphoneme, I agree with you. We all know why they do it, it's called "CYA", in case the charges are dropped or he is aquitted ... But in my opinion many times they go too far, and follow that to an absurdly extreme level. For example, I've seen something similar to this many times in the press: "Mrs Jones allegedly survived being attacked, raped, beaten, and strangled, by her estranged husband, Mr Jones". Obviously, there is nothing "alleged" about her surviving (either she did or she didn't), and there's nothing "alleged" about her having been attacked, etc...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Alleged**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/alleged)
(adjective) : said or thought by some people to be the stated bad or illegal thing, although you have no proof. (Cambridge dictionary).

> The sentence essentially says the **accused** man committed the crime. 
>   In my opinion, the writer has used "alleged" as a synonym for "accused", though in its objectionable sense.

Another fairer phrasing could be:

> - Bleeding profusely, she pleaded with her attacker- alleged to be Mushataq- to take her to a hospital.

It is routinely applied to actions,events, and things that have been asserted
but not proved.
In **Journalism**, the use of "allege or the relative adverb allegedly", protects
them from any libel suit.

Some [examples](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/alleged):

- Several alleged drug lords are to be put on trial.

  Opposition parties have protested over alleged vote rigging in the
  election

  They were in the house when the alleged crime took place.

Comment: +1 for spotting the issue that the attacker, whoever he was, was the person she pleaded with, so alleged makes no sense there, and seeing that the addition of the alleged name of the attacker is what caused the problem.

Comment: So it should be -she pleaded with the alleged attacker (without implying who he is/his name) to take her to a hospital.

Comment: or when to defend - e.g.- her alleged innocence.

Comment: @weakphoneme: no. "the alleged attacker" makes no sense. She pleaded with her attacker. It is ridiculous to assume she pleaded with a person she thought might have attacked her. The "alleged" belongs to the name, and the writer just mixed up two sentences that should have stayed apart: She pleaded with her attacker / Mr Mushataq is the alleged attacker.

Comment: "A foolish consistency ..." :-)

Comment: Alleged used prenominally is certainly an adjective rather than a verb, but a peripheral one. A large diamond is a diamond (intersection).  A fake diamond isn't (non-intersection). An alleged criminal??

Comment: The original phrasing acknowledges she was injured, but only tells us that this was "allegedly" as the result of an attack (for which Mushataq is the prime suspect). Your wording "she pleaded with her attacker - alleged to be Mushataq" asserts that she was attacked and that allegedly it was by Mushataq. This phrasing is even more absurd if Mushataq was the only person around, because if she was attacked by anyone, it must have been him. The newspaper covers itself while staying closest to the truth by their choice of phrasing - Either she was attacked by Mushataq or she "walked into a door."

Answer (score 6):

*[Alleged](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alleged)* is an adjective:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> [ATTRIBUTIVE]
>
> Said, without proof, to have taken place or to have a specified
>   illegal or undesirable quality:

In that sentence, it correctly modifies *attacker* as an adjectival use of the past participle *[form](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=alleged&searchmode=none)*:

> mid-15c., "quoted," past participle adjective from *allege*.
>
> Attested from 1610s in sense of "brought forth in court;" 1670s as
>   "asserted but not proved."

The adjectival use of verbs is quite common as you will find in this *[link](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/support-files/participle_adjectives_long_list.pdf)*.

---

As a third party news report in the public realm, inserting the adjective *alleged* is a professional practice to protect the author and publisher from legal liability. Though she did not plead with her *alleged* attacker, but with her attacker, the news reporter is prohibited by professional ethics and liability from communicating that assumption to the public, and the [**simplest** linguistic insertion of *alleged*](http://www.economist.com/blogs/prospero/2014/10/journalism-and-law) is a ubiquitous CYA technique in journalism.

> The obviously logical:
>
> - *Bleeding profusely, she pleaded with the attacker, Mushataq, to take  her to a hospital.*
>
> is transformed by liability considerations to:
>
> - *Bleeding profusely, she pleaded with the **alleged** attacker,
>     Mushataq, to take her to a hospital.*

Normally, people ignore the insertion, but from time to time, pedants make hay from the humorous ambiguities the added word can imply.

---

oxforddictionaries.com

www.etymonline.com

Comment: It seems you are saying is that the journalistic CYA usage of the word "alleged" has expanded its meaning to include: "accused (but un-convicted)."

Comment: Yes, @GoodA.M., an accusation is a specific kind of **assertion** (as implied in the etymology). The phrase "without proof" in the definition seems to be problematic in this usage, because the proof **exists** in the eyewitness testimony of the victim. It just hasn't been evaluated by a judge and jury.

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, as well as not judging who's guilty or lying, they should have said

- She reported that she pleaded with her attacker (allegedly Mushataq) to take her to the hospital.

Or, if she knew Mushataq:

- She reported that she pleaded with Mushataq (allegedly her attacker) to take her to the hospital.

But as noted, it's easier (and typical) for newspaper reporters/editors to just stick in "alleged", even though this caution often errs on the side of inaccuracy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd emphasize that "alleged" refers to a charge or claim, usually by authorities. And "alleged" is not a dodge to avoid libel charges, because, for one thing, it is not a defense for libel. If a statement is defamatory and untrue, that's libel per se. Publishing that a person "was an alleged embezzler" is actionable libel if it's not true.

"Alleged attacker" means the person who authorities are claiming to be the attacker.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at it this way. The attacker might have not attacked her. She could be bleeding because of her medical condition. The victim accuses the attacker but he might be proven innocent. Hence at the time he is alleged attacker.